# Synchronising samba and unix user accounts

Tags: samba

Is there an easy way to have a samba user automatically created whenever a unix user is created? Currently I'm using LDAP. But it is not that easy, and also very difficult to setup. I'm looking for a simpler way.

Comment: how do you create users?

Comment: i use this command `smbldap-useradd johndoe` or the way how a normal unix user is created `useradd johndoe`. Both create samba users automatically, but, the second solution requires the user to first login as a unix user to get the samba user activated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "smbpasswd -a " to set the users password in the Samba database, without requiring them to log in.

It should be possible to create a simple wrapper script which calls both useradd and smbpasswd -a. Ideally useradd should just have integration for this and call smbpasswd -a for you (perhaps after you've set a configuration option), but we're not quite there yet.